# docker container port command gives nothing

Tags: docker

I ran a nginx container without specifying the host port.

```
docker container run -d --name engineone nginx
```

When I check the running containers it shows that container I ran.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
d6b1d457b0b1        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   About an hour ago   Up 58 minutes       80/tcp              engineone
```

Now I want to know which port has taken by the `engineone` container. So I ran..

```
docker container port engineone
```

But the output gives nothing. I have some knowledge in how docker networking works but I would like to know how is this possible. Does it really runs without host port?

Comment: you didn't map any port `docker container run -d --name engineone nginx` ...  also in your list of running containers ... name of the container is `engine3` not `engineone`

Comment: Sorry it was typing mistake let's say it's the `engineone` container, But as Docker says it's Batteries included but removable. So when I ran `docker container port engineone` at-least it should return the default port right?

Comment: Which information do you geht when you use docker inspect engineone?

Comment: It gives soming like this...
`"Config": {
            "Hostname": "d8a2ca08c201",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },`
It seems default port 80 on host being used by the network...

Answer (score 1):

Done some research throughout the day, In docker docs..

> By default, when you create a container, it does not publish any of its ports to the outside world. To make a port available to services outside of Docker, or to Docker containers which are not connected to the container’s network, use the `--publish` or `-p` flag. This creates a firewall rule which maps a container port to a port on the Docker host.

So in here docker won't assign a port util we tell it to do.

Comment: What you wrote above is misleading. Docker does not map any port on the host if you don't ask explicitly. There is no such thing as "assign a port to a container which we will not know". Your nginx container exposes port 80 because [this was set at build time](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/a973c221f6cedede4dab3ab36d18240c4d3e3d74/mainline/buster/Dockerfile#L99). If you want to map that exposed port directly on the host, you need to do that when you run your container (e.g. `-p <hostport>:80`).